# How is attack bonus calculated for rapid shot?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, ranger

The description of rapid shot reads:

> You can get one extra attack per round with a ranged weapon. The attack is at your highest base attack bonus, but each attack you make in that round (the extra one and the normal ones) takes a -2 penalty. You must use the full attack action (see page 143) to use this feat.

Do you calculate the second attack with your highest base attack -2 as the only modifier or do you also apply your Dexterity bonus to the attack as you would for a regular ranged attack?

For example, if I have a dexterity bonus of +3 and a base attack bonus of +2 am I calculating the attack as +3+2-2=+3 or as +2-2=0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You take your total attack bonus for the attack, that is: any bonuses from weapon enhancements, ability modifiers and other sources, plus your highest **base** attack bonus.

Normally, every additional attack in a full attack round has its **base** attack bonus reduced by 5, but keeps all other bonuses.

In the case of Rapid Shot, you gain an additional attack when making a full attack action, but you don't have to reduce your base attack bonus by 5 for this additional attack. Instead, you may make this additional attack as if it was your first and most powerful attack.

If your **base** attack bonus (BAB) is +6, you can make a full attack action consisting of 2 attacks. The first attack is made with +6 BAB and the second with +1 BAB:

1. +6 BAB +3 Dex = +9 Attack Bonus
2. +1 BAB +3 Dex = +4 Attack Bonus

With Rapid Shot(RS) and its -2 Attack Bonus:

1. +6 BAB +3 Dex -2 RS = +7 Attack Bonus (Rapid Shot's additional attack)
2. +6 BAB +3 Dex -2 RS = +7 Attack Bonus
3. +1 BAB +3 Dex -2 RS = +2 Attack Bonus

Keep in mind that [you must always perform your attacks in order of highest **base** attack bonus to lowest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72425/8610).