# What are the penalties for the feat chain Weapon Focus(Shuriken)-Point Blank Shot-Rapid Shot-Two Weapon Fighting-Twin Throw?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I don't quite know how to calculate my to hit bonus for the following chain of feats. Please help. Please take to account the prerequisites are fulfilled.

Lv10 Rogue, BAB: +7/+2, Str 14, Dex 20, Weapon Focus Shuriken, Point Blank Shot.
Ring of Shurikens: swift act makes temporary +1 shurikens

Shuriken: +14/+9 TR19x2 Range 10 feet

Rapid Shot

Twin Throw

Two Weapon Fighting

Improved Two Weapon Fighting

Comment: Can you link to the magic item or special ability ring of shurikens? And what's the character's Str?

Comment: Ring of Shurikens....it's been a while. I believe I found it in an AEG supplement of Magic gear some time back in D&D 3.0 or 3.5. Basically we can't find the site or book any more so we Home Brewed it as a ring with Magic Weapon "Shurken" at will as a swift action so you can call and throw in the same action.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Any ol' order is fine. (The pattern I used below accumulates bonuses first alphabetically by bonus type then by source, penalties alphabetically by source, then situational bonuses then penalties. For sanity more than anything else.)

Answer (score 2):

The only really complicated part of this equation is the [two-weapon fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting) part; shuriken are considered light weapons for the purposes of two weapon fighting. I've assumed that the rogue consistently uses *+1 shuriken*.

- **Standard Attack:** +7 base +5 Dex +1 bonus *via* the feat [Weapon Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat-final/) (shuriken) +1 enhancement bonus *via* the *+1 shuriken* equals **+14 ranged** or +15 if target is within 30 ft. *via* the feat [Point Blank Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat-final/) (1d2+3/19-20 or 1d2+4/19-20 if target is within 30 ft., *+1 shuriken*)
- **Full Attack:** *(main hand)* +7 base +5 Dex  +1 bonus *via* the feat Weapon Focus (shuriken) +1 enhancement bonus *via* the *+1 shuriken* −2 penalty *via* the feat [Rapid Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-shot-combat-final/) −2 penalty *via* the feat [Two-weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/) equals **+10 twice *via* the feat [Twin Throw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/twin-throw-combat/)/+10/+5 ranged** or +11 twice/+11/+6 if target is within 30 ft. *via* the feat Point Blank Shot (1d2+3/19-20 or 1d2+4/19-20 if target is within 30 ft., *+1 shuriken*) **and** *(off-hand)* +7 base +5 Dex  +1 bonus *via* the feat Weapon Focus (shuriken) +1 enhancement bonus *via* the *+1 shuriken* −2 penalty *via* the feat Rapid Shot −2 penalty *via* the feat Two-weapon Fighting equals **+10/+5 ranged** or +11/+6 if target is within 30 ft. *via* the feat Point Blank Shot (1d2+2/19-20 or 1d2+3/19-20 if target is within 30 ft., *+1 shuriken*).

The thrower's Strength bonus to damage is halved for the thrower's off-hand attacks which is why main hand and off-hand attacks are separated in the Full Attack bullet. Had the rogue Str 10, the attacks could simply be run together as +10 twice/+10/+10/+5/+5. I wouldn't do that in case the rogue were to gain an in-combat bonus to his Strength, but a GM may prefer this second run-together format over the above format because [a typical creature makes its attacks in order from its attacks at its highest (base) attack bonus to its lowest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72425/8610), and this makes it clear *which* attacks should be made *when*. I've never had a GM *mandate* main hand and off-hand attacks be interleaved rather than just making *all* the main hand attacks then *all* the off-hand ones, but your GM might, and I appreciate her commitment to the rules.

To be clear, that *+10 twice/+10/+10/+5/+5* is +10 twice due to base attack bonus and the feat Twin Throw, +10 again from the feat Rapid Shot, +10 again from the first off-hand attack, +5 for the main hand iterative attack, and +5 again for the feat [Improved Two-weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/).

Keep in mind that the feat Two-weapon Fighting merely reduces penalties—anybody *can* two-weapon fight, but a dude with the feat Two-weapon Fighting is *better* at it. It's the feat Improved Two-weapon Fighting that adds a second and normally impossible off-hand attack at a −5 penalty, and it takes the feat [Greater Two-weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/)—for which this rogue doesn't yet meet the prerequisites—to get a *third* at −10.

Comment: This is more than enough. Thank you. Str 14 on PC if you want to know. However don't  you still get an extra attack form Improved Two Weapon Fighting at -5 penalty? So wouldn't be +10 TTf/+10/+5/+0?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver I think I've addressed that concern in the answer more fully now. Let me know if it needs further clarification.